# Подключить font IcoMoon во Vue.js

Tags: css, vue.js, webpack

При попытке подключить шрифт-иконки `chrome` выдает следующее:

```
Failed to decode downloaded font:

OTS parsing error: invalid version tag
```

Пробовал несколько разных иконок, не работает даже стандарный пак с [IcoMoon](https://icomoon.io/) (всегда делал через этот сайт) то есть проблема не в шрифте.

Вот мой `font-face`(файл: "icons.css"):

```
    @font-face {
  font-family: 'icomoon';
  src:  url('/icomoon.eot?');
  src:  url('/icomoon.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('/icomoon.ttf?') format('truetype'),
    url('/icomoon.woff?') format('woff'),
    url('/icomoon.svg?#icomoon') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

На всякий случай скажу что данный файл импортируется в `main.sass` вот так : `@import "icons"`

Проект создавал через `vue-cli`

p.s если убрать слеш вначале пути `vue` вообще выдает такую ошибку:

```
Error: Can't resolve './fonts/icomoon.eot'
```

Уже не знаю куда копать

Answer (score 2):

Решил вот так, изменил путь на: `"~@/assets/static/icons"` (файловая структура немного поменялась)